# trigger angular2-notifications via interceptor

Tags: angular

i have an interceptor code in my angular project which shows an alert for api response which i want to replace with angular2-notifications.

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet><app-spinner></app-spinner></router-outlet>
```

app.interceptor.ts

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private router: Router) {

    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const loaderContainer = document.getElementById("page-loader");
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
            loaderContainer.style.display = "block";
            // Clone the request to add the new header
            const clonedRequest = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', sessionStorage.getItem('token')) });
            // Pass the cloned request instead of the original request to the next handle
            return next.handle(clonedRequest).do(event => {

                // if the event is for http response
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    loaderContainer.style.display = "none";
                    // stop our loader here
                    //this._loadingBar.complete();
                }

            }, err => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    loaderContainer.style.display = "none";
                }
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (err.status == 401 || err.status == 403)) {
                    sessionStorage.clear();
                    this.router.navigate(['auth/login/simple']);
                    alert("sorry your session expire please logn to continue")
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

how do i replace "alert("sorry your session expire please logn to continue")" with angular2-notifications toaster ?

i am unable to figure out where to keep

```
<simple-notifications [options]="options"></simple-notifications>
```

in which file and how do i trigger it via interceptor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the `<simple-notifications [options]="options"></simple-notifications>` in your main component html.

And you have to import and inject **NotificationsService** to the interceptor's constructor

```
import { NotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';

constructor(
          private router: Router,
          private notificationsService: NotificationsService
        ) {}
```

Then in the `intercept` method you can create the notification using notification service.

```
`this._notifications.create(title, content, type, temp);`
```

Find the official demo for [angular2-notifications](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example?file=app%2Fexample.component.ts)